# How can crop an image of any size to a certain dimension?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, crop

My requirement is When I handle an image of any dimension that image should be cropped automatically to a dimension of 320x240 without any stretch. How can I write a crop method for this functionality? I mean I've list of images with various dimensions if i pick an image from this list it will be automatically converted to the dimension 320x 240. How can I achieve it. Please advise me.

Now I'm using the following coding :
http://www.abdus.me/ios-programming-tips/resize-image-in-ios/

But the quality of the  resultant image is not good it gets blurred. Could you please tell me how can I overcome this issue.

Comment: You mean crop or resize. As if it's about cropping then, which portion of image would you like to crop, like center, upper-left etc?

Comment: either it may be crop or resize but we need the resultant image size should in the dimension of 320x240 with out lack of quality... If it is crop means, cropping should be from center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***For crop - Portion of image :***

```
- (UIImage*) getSubImageFrom: (UIImage*) img WithRect: (CGRect) rect {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // translated rectangle for drawing sub image
    CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(-rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y, img.size.width, img.size.height);

    // clip to the bounds of the image context
    // not strictly necessary as it will get clipped anyway?
    CGContextClipToRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height));

    // draw image
    [img drawInRect:drawRect];

    // grab image
    UIImage* subImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return subImage;
}
```

***For Resize*** -

Put the UIImageView's frame into 320x240 and then `imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`

Comment: this code works good. but the image is getting blurred slightly.